# How to add MenuStripItems dynamically with images

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a question to add items by finding the file in the directory.
This script works.

```
Private Sub LoadAddItemsToEditMenu(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(".\MenuItems\Edit")
        Dim mainMenuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem(IO.Path.GetFileName(dir))

        For Each fn As String In Directory.GetFiles(dir)

            Dim subMenuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn))

                subMenuItem.Tag = fn

            EditToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subMenuItem)

            AddHandler subMenuItem.Click, AddressOf EditExtendetItem_Click
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I need to still tune to each item added to a picture of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you are asking for this exactly, the code below adds a icon of the file on each item. I hope this works for you:

```
Private Sub LoadAddItemsToEditMenu(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(".\MenuItems\Edit")
    Dim mainMenuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem(IO.Path.GetFileName(dir))

    For Each fn As String In Directory.GetFiles(dir)

        Dim subMenuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn))

            subMenuItem.Tag = fn
            subMenuItem.Image = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fn).ToBitmap

            EditToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subMenuItem)

        AddHandler subMenuItem.Click, AddressOf EditExtendetItem_Click
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Working! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the way above should do the job. However, I would advice you to add handler before you add the item to container. It looks better and is easier to read/ debug. By the way, I know that VB.net has a "With" prefix, a little bit comparable to using...I would use it, if I were you and if you dont mind a well-mind advice (or did you rewrited the code especially for stackoverflow to help others to understand your code? If so-> never mind) .

Comment: Consider adding code to your answer to back up what you are saying or if it's meant to be a comment to the other answer consider waiting until you have the relevant rep to do so. I appreciate you have to put a bit of work in to get there but as it stands this isn't really and answer.

Comment: @Bugs: Thanx a lot for a good advice to a newbie on stackoverflow. I'll consider it in my next Answer. I never mind to annoy someone, just tried to help as far as I could without any code editor on my phone, but there it is - a direct downvote. Ok, next time than...